# How can I write this equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I just want to know how can I write this equation in latex? I mean the equation in the picture, how much description should I make?  [image: the one in the picture]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! With use of `cases` environment from `amsmath˙package ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
P_{s,t}^{WT}=\begin{dcases}
0                                           &   V_{s,t}^{WT} \leq V_{ci}            \\
p_r\times\biggl(\frac{V_{s,t}^{WT}-V_{c,t}}
                    {V_t - V_{ci}}\biggr)^3 &   V_{ci} \le V_{t,s}^{WT} \le V_{cr}  \\
p_r                                         &   V_r \le V_{t,s}^{WT} \le V_{co}   \\[1ex]
0                                           &   V_{t,s}^{WT} \ge V_{co}  
            \end{dcases} \qquad\forall s,t                  
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico, corrected now. ... actually this could correct OP ;-). Thank you!

Comment: @Zarko thank you very much for your kind help